# Realm-js schema with nested objects

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to easily query such results:

```
[{
  name: 'john_doe',
  info: {
    age: 24,
    notes: 'custom text',
    phoneNumbers: {
      home: 112345678,
      work: 1234567,
    },
  },
}, {...}, {...}...]
```

... by such query:

```
contacts.filtered("info.age = 24 AND info.notes CONTAINS 'custom'");
```

How should i create such schema? docs are very confusing about data types and nested properties:

- https://realm.io/docs/react-native/0.14.0/api/Realm.html#~PropertyType
- https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#nested-objects

I do not need to retrieve any parts of this data separately - only complete object with all nested objects at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all fields into a single object:

```
var ContactSchema = {
    name: 'Contact',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: 'int',
        notes: 'string',
        homePhone: 'string',
        workPhone: 'string'        
    }
};
```

Alternatively you could create child objects for info and phoneNumbers but if you are not sharing this data across multiple contacts then this probably isn't needed.